# Several sets of values with Yesql

Tags: clojure

Is it possible with [Yesql](https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql) to construct inserts that have several sets of values, such as:

```
INSERT INTO used_tools
(user_id, tool_id)
VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)
```

where the amount of sets it's variable from execution to execution?

Comment: [Sounds like it](https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql/issues/51). I'm not ready to delve into the details, so feel free to create an answer out of that!

Comment: @D-side: am I misreading it? It sounds like it's not possible from that open issue.

Comment: That's why I didn't rush with an answer. There is an example for plain JDBC that should be able to do the above, but for tuples in general... Yep, can't find anything either.